# Random value not in the range of array/dictionary

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dictionary, random

I just started learning Javascript this week to write a wordgame to help my kid. The idea is that it should show and play a `random` word from a `dictionary`, she writes it the `entry` is checked and `random` gets deleted from the `dictionary`. The game continues until the dictionary `length===0`, and the wrong words are summarised if there are any. Somehow, the program is unpredictable, it literally works 1 in 7 times, and I can't understand why. Giving the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'word' of undefined

I do think it has something the do with the way I delete `random`, or check if the `dictonary` is empty. Underneath the code is pasted links to screenshots of the console.log; 1 is the result of the program completely finishing, the other of one that doesn't. The interesting thing is that the error also is unpredictable, sometimes after just 1 word, sometimes 2. The only thing I do is refresh the page and the program behaves differently. I also tried running it on different browsers.

Being a total noob, I was quite surprised that I get different results while trying to do the same thing. It was quite frustrating to find out what was happening :-)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aliyah's dictee spel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <h1>Hej! Velkommen til Aliyahs diktee!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Random_word">
        <h2 id="Empty">Click start to start</h2>
        <button id="startGame">Start</button>
        <button id="editList">Edit word list</button>
        <h3 id="correctWord"></h3>

    </div>
    <script>
    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    var dictionary = [
        {   word: "apple",
            audio: 'apple.mp3',
        },
        {
            word: "baby",
            audio: 'baby.mp3',
        },
        {
            word: "car",
            audio: 'car.mp3'
        }

    ];

    var wordsWrong = [];
    var wordsCorrectCounter = 0;
    var wordsWrongCounter = 0;
    //var cheer = new Audio('correct.mp3');
    //var boo = new Audio('wrong.mp3');

    function editWords(){
        console.log("under construction");
    };

    function startGame(){
        document.getElementById("startGame").remove();
        document.getElementById("editList").remove();
        newWord(dictionary);
    };
    
    async function newWord(dictionary)
    {
        if (Object.entries(dictionary).length === 0){
            endGame();
        }
            else {
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length);
                document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = dictionary[random].word;
                console.log(dictionary[random].word);
                console.log(dictionary);
                await sleep(2000);
                document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "       ";
                createInputField(random);
            }
    };

    function createInputField(random)
    {
        var entry = document.createElement("input");
        entry.setAttribute("type", "text");
        entry.id = "inputfield";
        document.body.appendChild(entry);
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.id = "okBtn";
        btn.innerHTML = "ok";
        btn.type = "submit";
        btn.name = "answerBtn";
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
        document.getElementById("okBtn").addEventListener("click", () => checkAnswer(random, entry.value));
    };

    function checkAnswer(random, entry)
        {var answer = entry.toLowerCase();
    
        if (dictionary[random].word == answer){
            //cheer.play();
            wordsCorrectCounter += 1;
            document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
            document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
            delete dictionary[random];
            console.log(dictionary);
            newWord(dictionary);
        }
            else{
                wordsWrong.push(dictionary[random].word);
                wordsWrongCounter += 1;
                document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
                document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
                //boo.play();
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                document.getElementById("correctWord").innerHTML = dictionary[random].word;
                let btn = document.createElement("button");
                btn.id = "contBtn";
                btn.innerHTML = "Continue";
                btn.type = "submit";
                btn.name = "continueBtn";
                document.body.appendChild(btn);
                document.getElementById("contBtn").addEventListener("click", () => wrongAnswer(random));
            }
    };

    function wrongAnswer(random){
        document.getElementById("contBtn").remove();
        document.getElementById("correctWord").innerHTML = "    "
        delete dictionary[random];
        newWord(dictionary);
    };

    function endGame()
    {
        document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "you are done!" + "Correct: " + wordsCorrectCounter + "Wrong: " + wordsWrongCounter 
        + "These words were wrong: " + wordsWrong;
        

    };

    function Refresh() {
        window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
    };
 
    document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", () => startGame());



    

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Console.log when program is able to finish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cerR9.png)

[Console.log when program gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX8pU.png)

Comment: means your random value is not in the range of your array

Comment: Easier thing than random is just shuffle the array at the start and read the first index and remove it.

Comment: Consider editing your question to display the console logs as text instead of images. Had you done that, I'd give you an up arrow.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I considered it, but it looked like it was less reader friendly than a print screen and didn't seem to give any benefit since you wouldn't need to copy/paste it. Well, at least that is what I thought. But I definitely will next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Explain

```
dictionary = [
    { word: "apple", audio: 'apple.mp3', },
    { word: "baby", audio: 'baby.mp3', },
    { word: "car", audio: 'car.mp3' }
];
```

you genrate a random index let's say `2`
you can jsut use 2 and extract the word by `dictionary[2].word`

if you pass the **random index**
it could be **invalid** after you **remove item from dictionary**
which is why you get the error

for example:
you have the **old** random index `2`
but you have already remove the item
the current dictionary is

```
dictionary = [
    { word: "apple", audio: 'apple.mp3', },
    { word: "baby", audio: 'baby.mp3', },
];
```

and then you try to access `dictionary[2]`
which doesn't exist anymore

## Remove Item from Array

you can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let dictionary = [
    { word: "apple", audio: 'apple.mp3', },
    { word: "baby", audio: 'baby.mp3', },
    { word: "car", audio: 'car.mp3' }
];
// only the item that item.word != "apple" will pass this
dictionary = dictionary.filter(item => item.word != "apple");

console.log(dictionary);
```

## String and Variable

[Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
use this to set string, it more readable & easier to edit
you can put variable in it by use `${variable_name}`

example:

```js
let x = "test";
console.log(`this is a ${x}`);
```

## Find specific item in Array

I see you have audio file
If you need to find the item in dictionary
You can use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
Because we only pass word now
We can use it to find it
Let's say you want to find audio for `apple`
It will be like this

```js
let dictionary = [
            { word: "apple", audio: 'apple.mp3', },
            { word: "baby", audio: 'baby.mp3', },
            { word: "car", audio: 'car.mp3' }
        ],
    target = dictionary.find(item => item.word=="apple"),
    audio = false;
if(target) audio = target.audio;
console.log(audio);
```

## Complete Answer

I have add the comment in, you can check it

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Aliyah's dictee spel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Hej! Velkommen til Aliyahs diktee!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Random_word">
        <h2 id="Empty">Click start to start</h2>
        <button id="startGame">Start</button>
        <button id="editList">Edit word list</button>
        <h3 id="correctWord"></h3>

    </div>
    <script>
        function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }

        var dictionary = [
            { word: "apple", audio: 'apple.mp3', },
            { word: "baby", audio: 'baby.mp3', },
            { word: "car", audio: 'car.mp3' }
        ];

        var wordsWrong = [];
        var wordsCorrectCounter = 0;
        var wordsWrongCounter = 0;
        //var cheer = new Audio('correct.mp3');
        //var boo = new Audio('wrong.mp3');

        function editWords() {
            console.log("under construction");
        }

        function startGame() {
            document.getElementById("startGame").remove();
            document.getElementById("editList").remove();
            newWord();
        }

        // dictionary is global variable, you don't need to pass it to access it
        async function newWord() {

            // I add this so the color will be reset after click continue
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "";

            if (Object.entries(dictionary).length === 0) {
                endGame();
            } else {
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length),
                    // get the random word here when it still exist in dictionary
                    random_word = dictionary[random].word;

                document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = random_word;
                console.log(random_word);
                console.log(dictionary);
                await sleep(2000);
                document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "       ";

                // direct pass the ramdom word, not the ramdom index
                // ramdom index could be invalid after you remove item from dictionary
                // which is why you get the error
                createInputField(random_word);
            }
        }

        function createInputField(random_word) {
            var entry = document.createElement("input");
            entry.setAttribute("type", "text");
            entry.id = "inputfield";
            document.body.appendChild(entry);
            let btn = document.createElement("button");
            btn.id = "okBtn";
            btn.innerHTML = "ok";
            btn.type = "submit";
            btn.name = "answerBtn";
            document.body.appendChild(btn);
            document.getElementById("okBtn").addEventListener("click", () => checkAnswer(random_word, entry.value));
        }

        function checkAnswer(random_word, entry) {
            var answer = entry.toLowerCase();

            if (random_word == answer) {
                //cheer.play();

                // if you only need +1, you can use ++
                wordsCorrectCounter++;

                document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
                document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();

                // use Array.filter() to remove random_word(answer) from the dictionary
                // only word != random_word will pass
                dictionary = dictionary.filter(item => item.word != random_word);
                console.log(dictionary);
                newWord();
            } else {
                // I didn't see this, so I add it
                // if you only need +1, you can use ++
                wordsWrongCounter++;

                // because we pass the random_word(answer) now, we can just push it
                wordsWrong.push(random_word);

                document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
                document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
                //boo.play();
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                document.getElementById("correctWord").innerHTML = random_word;
                
                let btn = document.createElement("button");
                btn.id = "contBtn";
                btn.innerHTML = "Continue";
                btn.type = "submit";
                btn.name = "continueBtn";
                document.body.appendChild(btn);

                document.getElementById("contBtn").addEventListener("click", () => wrongAnswer(random_word));
            }
        }

        function wrongAnswer(random_word) {
            document.getElementById("contBtn").remove();
            document.getElementById("correctWord").innerHTML = "    ";
            // same as above
            // use Array.filter() to remove correct_word(answer) from the dictionary
            // only word != correct_word will pass
            dictionary = dictionary.filter(item => item.word != random_word);
            newWord();
        }

        function endGame() {
            /*
            use `` to set string, it more readable & easier to edit
            you can put variable in it by use ${variable_name}

            example: 
            let x = "test";
            console.log(`this is a ${x}`);
            
            result:
            this is a test
            */
            document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML =
                `you are done! Correct: ${wordsCorrectCounter} Wrong: ${wordsWrongCounter} These words were wrong: ${wordsWrong}`;
        }

        function Refresh() {
            window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
        }

        document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", () => startGame());
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very insightful! Also the extra feedback in between was immensely helpful.  I did not quite get the audio bit, but I used '''var audio = new Audio(dictionary[random].audio); audio.play()''' it works, but if that's not the proper way I'm open to suggestions :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I just got the issue in your code, it's a bit conceptual thing and nothing much.

[See what's going wrong in this screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdZry.png)

You can see there the length of the dictionary(array) is still the same after deleting the word(object).
Because you have used: `delete` keyword which deletes an item and replaces it with `empty` and size of the array remains the same.
Hence the new dictionary after deleting the first word became: `[empty, {...}, {...}]`
Now whenever you will try to get `dictionary[0].word` *gives you an error: Cannot read property of undefine, because it's empty*

Instead of using `delete` keyword you can simply use `dictionary.splice(random, 1)`

[See the console screenshot after using splice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCluI.png)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aliyah's dictee spel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Hej! Velkommen til Aliyahs diktee!</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="Random_word">
    <h2 id="Empty">Click start to start</h2>
    <button id="startGame">Start</button>
    <button id="editList">Edit word list</button>
    <h3 id="correctWord"></h3>

  </div>
  <script>
    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    var dictionary = [{
        word: "apple",
        audio: 'apple.mp3',
      },
      {
        word: "baby",
        audio: 'baby.mp3',
      },
      {
        word: "car",
        audio: 'car.mp3'
      }

    ];

    var wordsWrong = [];
    var wordsCorrectCounter = 0;
    var wordsWrongCounter = 0;
    var cheer = new Audio('correct.mp3');
    var boo = new Audio('wrong.mp3');

    function editWords() {
      console.log("under construction");
    };

    function startGame() {
      document.getElementById("startGame").remove();
      document.getElementById("editList").remove();
      newWord(dictionary);
    };

    async function newWord(dictionary) {
      if (Object.entries(dictionary).length === 0) {
        endGame();
      } else {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length);
        console.log(random)
        document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = dictionary[random].word;
        console.log(dictionary[random].word);
        console.log(dictionary);
        await sleep(2000);
        document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "       ";
        createInputField(random);
      }
    };

    function createInputField(random) {
      var entry = document.createElement("input");
      entry.setAttribute("type", "text");
      entry.id = "inputfield";
      document.body.appendChild(entry);
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.id = "okBtn";
      btn.innerHTML = "ok";
      btn.type = "submit";
      btn.name = "answerBtn";
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
      document.getElementById("okBtn").addEventListener("click", () => checkAnswer(random, entry.value));
    };

    function checkAnswer(random, entry) {
      var answer = entry.toLowerCase();

      if (dictionary[random].word == answer) {
        cheer.play();
        wordsCorrectCounter += 1;
        document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
        document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
        dictionary.splice(random, 1);
        console.log(dictionary);
        newWord(dictionary);
      } else {
        wordsWrong.push(dictionary[random].word);
        wordsWrongCounter += 1;
        document.getElementById("okBtn").remove();
        document.getElementById("inputfield").remove();
        boo.play();
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("correctWord").innerHTML = dictionary[random].word;
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.id = "contBtn";
        btn.innerHTML = "Continue";
        btn.type = "submit";
        btn.name = "continueBtn";
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
        document.getElementById("contBtn").addEventListener("click", () => wrongAnswer(random));
      }
    };

    function wrongAnswer(random) {
      document.getElementById("contBtn").remove();
      document.getElementById("correctWord").innerHTML = "    "
      delete dictionary[random];
      newWord(dictionary);
    };

    function endGame() {
      document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = "you are done!" + "Correct: " + wordsCorrectCounter + "Wrong: " + wordsWrongCounter +
        "These words were wrong: " + wordsWrong;


    };

    function Refresh() {
      window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
    };

    document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", () => startGame());
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did try that method, somehow I had trouble with that as well. Using filter.array() instead did the trick for me. Thanks!